# Not able to receive the OnBarCodeEvent for zebra scanner in linux c++

Tags: c++, linux, barcode-scanner

I am using the zebra linux sdk for scanner to capture the barcode that is scanned.
I want to listen to the `OnBarcodeEvent` and capture the code.

I have tried the sample console-app code and gui app code

I have called the

```
::ExecCommand( CMD_REGISTER_FOR_EVENTS , inXml, outXml, &eStatus);
```

The `OnBarcodeEvent` doesn't get invoked when I scan a bar code.

Code provided below.

```
void SampleEventListener::connect_corescanner()
{

    cout <<"connect_corescanner startp"<< endl;

    int iScannerType = SCANNER_TYPE_ALL;
    StatusID eStatus ;

    ::Open(this, SCANNER_TYPE_ALL , &eStatus );
    std::cout << "Open eStatus line 634 ConsoleSampleEventListener.cpp" << ": " << eStatus << std::endl;

    if ( eStatus != STATUS_OK )
    {
        cout <<eStatus<< endl;
        cout <<"can't connect to the corescanner. "<< endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    // register for all events //
    std::string inXml;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "<inArgs>" << std::endl;
    oss << "    <cmdArgs>" << std::endl;
    oss << "        <arg-int>6</arg-int>" << std::endl;
    oss << "        <arg-int>1,2,4,8,16,32</arg-int>" << std::endl;
    oss << "    </cmdArgs>" << std::endl;
    oss << "</inArgs>" ;
    inXml = oss.str();

    std::string outXml;
    ::ExecCommand( CMD_REGISTER_FOR_EVENTS , inXml, outXml, &eStatus);
    std::cout << "ExecCommand eStatus line 658 ConsoleSampleEventListener.cpp" << ": " << eStatus << std::endl;
    if( eStatus != STATUS_OK ){
        cout <<"unable to register for events"<< endl;

        exit(-1);
    }

    cout <<"subscribe to events successful."<< outXml;
    cout <<"\nsubscribe to events successful."<< endl;

    cout <<"connect_corescanner endp\n"<< endl;

}


void SampleEventListener::OnBarcodeEvent(short int eventType, std::string & pscanData)
{
    cout << "Barcode Detected" << endl;
    cout << "Out XML" << endl;
    cout << pscanData << endl;
}
```